# Pause song for 10 seconds then start playing

Tags: c#

Working on a Valentines gift for my wife and I wanted the mp3 song to start to play after 10 seconds. What I have works but for some reason it starts right away and I can't figure out why.

```
    for (int x = 1; x < 20; x++)//60
    {
        switch (x)
        {
            case 19://59
                mplayerlevel2.URL = "All of you John Legend.mp3";
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think c# will take exactly .5 seconds to execute a do nothing loop

Comment: What library are you using to play the song? Have you heard about [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)?

Comment: *Assuming WinForms, based on your previous questions. WHERE is this code running? The `Load()` event of the Form?...`Click()` event of a Button maybe? Something else?

Comment: Nyssa I wanted to have a screen showing an animated heart and then a few seconds later it will play that song.

Comment: IDLE mind I've never heard of NAudio. Is it good? I just looked on youtube on how to play an mp3 song and followed their directions. Ive never done that before.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `Task` to execute in the future and then keep executing your program in the meantime.

```
Task
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    .GetAwaiter()
    .OnCompleted(() =>
    {
        mplayerlevel2.URL = "All of you John Legend.mp3";
    });
```

Comment: IvySoftware thou does rock!!! It worked like a charm!!! I don't have enough reputation to give you a positive feedback. When I do, I'll come back here and give it to you. Thank you so much. Ive been working on this trying to figure it out for a while.

Comment: @TheOnion13 I believe that since it's your own question you have the ability to click '✔' and accept an answer regardless of reputation. Regardless of which answer you ultimately accept, _your own_ reputation will also increase as a result of accepting an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming WinForms and a Button Click event, put `async` in the method signature and use `await Task.Delay()`:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    mplayerlevel2.URL = "All of you John Legend.mp3";
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

From your further comments:

> I wanted to have a screen showing an animated heart and then a few
> seconds later it will play that song

I think you'd better off with a TIMER set to 10 seconds. You can put your animated GIF in a PictureBox (it'll animate on its own when the form opens), then in the `Tick()` event of the Timer, start your music:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tmr = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        tmr.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds;
        tmr.Tick += Tmr_Tick;
        tmr.Start();
    }

    private void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        mplayerlevel2.URL = "All of you John Legend.mp3";
    }

}
```

You could alternatively drop the Timer from your ToolBox onto your form and set it up that way instead of creating it through code as I have done.

Comment: See I originally had it like this but it stopped playing after a few seconds and I couldn't figure out why.     int x = 1;             x++;
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(GameTimer_Tick);
            if (x > 10)
            {
                mplayer.URL = "All of you John Legend.mp3";
            }
            else
            {

            }

Comment: I also wanted it to play on its own without using a button

Comment: You can do the same thing with the `Load()` or `Shown()` event of the form, which fires only once when the form first opens.

Answer (score -1):

i'd use a native sleep function, which is made for this :

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Blocking the main thread for 10 seconds?

Comment: yes. it's a valentine's gift for his wife, how is that a problem ? my answer fits his needs